# make a post request with a body in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, request

I am using nodeJS to communicate with an API. 
To do that, I am using a post request.

In my code, I use form data to pass the variables, but I get error 400. When I try to put body instead, I get an error saying that my variables are undefined.

This is the API: https://developer.hpe.com/api/simplivity/endpoint?&path=%2Fdatastores

My request:

```
async function postCreateDatastore(url, username, password, name, clusterID, policyID, size, token) {
    console.log (name, clusterID, policyID, size)
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + '/datastores',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.simplivity.v1.1+json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        formdata:
        {
            name: name,
            omnistack_cluster_id: clusterID,
            policy_id: policyID,
            size: size,
        }
    };
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode === 415) {
                console.log(body);
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                console.log("passed");
                console.log(JSON.parse(body));
                resolve(response.statusCode);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

the answer:

```
testsimon20K 4a298cf0-ff06-431a-9c86-d8f9947ba0ba ea860974-9152-4884-a607-861222b8da4d 20000
passed
{ exception:
   'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException',
  path: '/api/datastores',
  message:
   'Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.simplivity.restapi.v1.controller.DatastoreController.createDatastore(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.simplivity.restapi.v1.mo.actions.CreateDatastoreMO) throws org.apache.thrift.TException,org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException,com.simplivity.restapi.exceptions.ObjectNotFoundException,java.text.ParseException,java.io.IOException,com.simplivity.util.exceptions.ThriftConnectorException,com.simplivity.common.exceptions.DataSourceException',
  timestamp: '2019-07-04T08:51:49Z',
  status: '400' }
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to post your data. This package let you use the default fetch function from ES6.

Here is your answer:

```js
//require the node-fetch function
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function postCreateDatastore(url, username, password, name, clusterID, policyID, size, token) {
    console.log(name, clusterID, policyID, size);
    
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${url}/datastores`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          omnistack_cluster_id: clusterID,
          policy_id: policyID,
          size
        })
      });
    
      const json = await response.json();
    
      console.log(json);

      return json;
    }
    catch(e) {
      throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your help. testing this asap. Is there a way to stay with my request or I am forced to change the way I do it? 
I have to use resolve since I am waiting on a promise in the function that calls this one.

Comment: I think you can use request but i'll just prefer fetch because it is implemented in the default JS. Instead of using promise you can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: i get this error with your code aswell :  message:
   'Can not deserialize instance of com.simplivity.restapi.v1.mo.actions.CreateDatastoreMO out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@a142723; line: 1, column: 1]',

Comment: @luckysimon I think it is something with the key. I changed the contenttype to json.

Comment: no it is that content type, i get error 415 if I use application/json ```{ exception: 'org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException',
  path: '/api/datastores',
  message: 'Content type \'application/json\' not supported',
  timestamp: '2019-07-04T11:10:04Z',
  status: '415' }```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195989/discussion-between-oscar-r-and-lucky-simon).